# Error: allocating an object of abstract class type 'JIntent'

Tags: android, c++, c++builder, firemonkey

How fix this error?

Code:

```
Intent *JIntent; //main.h
//menu.cpp
Intent = new JIntent(this); //Error
```

and Create Class:

```
class TestClass
{
    public:
        JIntent *MyIntent;
        JService *MyService;
        virtual int FuncClass() = 0;
};

int TestClass::FuncClass() {
    MyIntent = new JIntent(this);
    MyService = new JService(this);

}
```

Does not work. I don't understand this.

Comment: Pozharov Show the constructor of class  JIntent  and what error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

`JIntent` and `JService` are abstract interfaces, you cannot instantiate them directly.  For `JIntent`, you must instantiate the `TJIntent` class instead, and assign it to a `_di_JIntent` variable (which wraps the interface to handle reference counting for you);

```
#include <Androidapi.JNI.App.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText.hpp>

class TestClass
{
    public:
        _di_JIntent MyIntent;
        _di_JService MyService;
        virtual int FuncClass() = 0;
};
```

```
int TestClass::FuncClass() {
    MyIntent = new TJIntent;
    MyService = ...;
}
```

That being said, `JService` represents Android's [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) class.  There is an accompanied `TJService` class, but it is meant to be *derived* from, not *instantiated*.  Delphi/C++Builder do not natively support implementing Android services yet, though it is technically possible with some extra work (involving a Java stub):

[Delphi and Android services](http://blog.blong.com/2013/11/delphi-and-android-services.html)

[Delphi and Android services (part 2)](http://blog.blong.com/2013/11/delphi-and-android-services-part-2.html)

Answer (score -1):

How this fix? This error..
JIntent - class

```
#include<Androidapi.JNI.App.hpp> //JService
#include<Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText.hpp> //JIntent
```

It's FireMonkey

Comment: This does not answer the question.